# can't find IfxBulkCopy in IBM.Data.Informix 2.81.0.0

Tags: asp.net, sql, informix, bulkinsert, data-migration

Q:

My question consists of two parts:

1- I want to use the following class `IfxBulkCopy` to insert large amount of data but this class doesn't exist in the **dll** `IBM.Data.Informix 2.81.0.0` how to fix this problem.?

**Note :** the class exist in the  `IBM.Data.Informix 9.0.0.2` !but i can't use this version because we use an old version of the `informix`.
When i use the new version i get the following exception :

```
Invalid argument

StackTrace = "   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.ReplaceConnectionStringParms(String szValue, IfxConnSettings& connSettings)\r\n   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)\r\n   at Common.DBConnectionForInformix..ctor(String ConnectionStr...
```

## My .cs:

```
 public static void InsertAsBulk(DataTable dt)
        {


            using (IfxConnection cn = new IfxConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aa"].ToString()))
            {

                cn.Open();
                using (IfxBulkCopy copy = new IfxBulkCopy(cn))
                {
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2);
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, 3);
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, 4);
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, 5);
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(5, 6);
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(6, 7);

                    copy.DestinationTableName = "schday";
                    copy.WriteToServer(dt);
                }
            }

        }
```

2- Is the `IfxBulkCopy` use the transaction concept during the insertion operation or may result inconsistent data also .

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: `<add name="aa" connectionString="User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;Host=x;Server=x_tcp;Service=x_tcp;Database=x; Client Locale=ar_ae.1256; Database Locale=ar_ae.8859-6; Protocol=olsoctcp" providerName="IBM.Data.Informix"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string is fine. Do you have multiple versions of driver installed? I had same problem when I installed OAT, Informix driver and Informix Client SDK on same machine.
This solved my problem:
1. Uninstallation of driver and client sdk + windows restart
2. Installation of Client SDK together with data server driver
3. Checking system PATH variable. I added

```
C:\Program Files\IBM Informix Client SDK\bin  
C:\Program Files\IBM Informix Client SDK\bin\netf20
```

to system PATH. I'm not sure what was the problem, maybe just changing PATH variable (without unistallation) can fix it.